# Analysis into noughts and crosses strategy

Tags: analysis, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I was reading this [paper](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/31035/2/buzzciere8.pdf) that analyses some strategies of the game dots and boxes. To understand this concept I tried to apply some of the techniques used in the paper to other games such as noughts and crosses.

For example: in the game dots and boxes you may represent a board by the notation of $G$ (game) = $H$ (the moves played previously) $+ 3 + 4$ where $3$ and $4$ are "chains" that is to say rows of unfilled boxes on the grid. Extending this you can prove that certain moves are optimal in certain circumstances by looking at the value $v(G)$ of certain moves.

How could you use these principles to show for example that an optimal move on a noughts and crosses game is to start by playing in one of the corners.

Comment: Playing in one of the corners is *not* the optimal first move in tic-tac-toe (as we Yanks call it).

Comment: I suppose that's somewhat up to interpretation. The general consensus I can see online is that starting in the corner is optimal however, if the opponent plays well then they can still guarantee a tie and in a sense if we're going off the definition of optimal meaning it can give the most possible ways of winning (ignoring any latter moves) then the center would be the best.

Comment: Where "online" is telling you that the corner is the best move?

Comment: This link: [link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-is-the-optimal-first-move-in-tic-tac-toe)

Comment: That's a reasonable explanation, and I guess it's kind of arbitrary for me to say the center is better based on number of winning lines, when either choice ends in a draw based on perfect play. I'm also thinking by analogy of $3^3$, $3^4$, ..., $3^n$ tic-tac-toe played on a hypercube of sidelength $3$, where playing in the center is **the** winning move, even if the second player is the one to claim it.